# A is prime over B, then A is also atomic over B

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The definition of $A$ is atomic over $B$ is:

> Let $A$ be a model and $B \subset A$. An element $a \in A$ is atomic
>   over $B$ if the type $\text{tp}(a/B)$ is isolated. If each element $a \in A$ is atomic over $B$, we say that $A$ is *atomic* over $B$.

The question is about the following exercise:

> Let $A$ be a model of some theory $T$ and $B$ be a subset of $A$. We
>   will say that $A$ is *prime* over $B$, if any partial elementary map
>   $B \to M$ extends to an elementary map $A \to M$.
>
> Show that if $T$ is totally transcendental and $A$ is prime over $B$,
>   then $A$ is also atomic over $B$.

I don't understand why you need $T$ totally transcendental. Can't we just say: for $a \in A$ suppose that $p = \text{tp}(a/B)$ is not isolated. Then by the omitting types theorem there is a model $M$ of $\text{Th}_B(A)$ that omits $p$. Since $A \equiv M$ in the language $L_B$ there is an elementary map $f : B \to M$. By the assumption $A$ is prime over $B$, we can extend this map to an elementary map $f' :A \to M \supset f$. Therefore we see that $p$ must be omitted in $A$ as well, but by definition it is realized by $a \in A$. Contradiction: $p$ must be isolated.

This is basically the same proof as for $A$ is prime $\Rightarrow$ $A$ is atomic.

Comment: Hint: Your argument implicitly assumes that $B$ is countable.

Comment: A correct answer to this exercise requires developing the theory of *constructible* extensions. Is this something that has been done in your course?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think so, but not much. I know that if $A$ is constructible over $B$, then it is also atomic over $B$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ahh, yes! The omitting types theorem is only for countable languages. $L_B$ is not countable if $B$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion in the comments settles the question of why your argument doesn't work. Note that it works in the countable case (and the statement is true without the totally transcendental hypothesis in this case), but the theorem is also true for uncountable $B$ when $T$ is totally transcendental.

To prove it in the uncountable case, we use the notion of constructibility. Here are the three crucial facts, which come together to easily solve the exercise:

1. If $T$ is totally transcendental, then constructible extensions exist: for every subset $B$ of a model of $T$, there is a model $M\models T$ such that $M$ is constructible over $B$. (You probably proved this in your course. If not, this is the hard part of the exercise.)
2. If $M$ is constructible over $B$, then $M$ is atomic over $B$. (In the comments, you said that you know this fact).
3. If $M$ is atomic over $B$, and $B\subseteq N\preceq M$, then $N$ is atomic over $B$. (This is easy).

Comment: I don't understand (3). Is that a typo? What is $N$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo - fixed. $N$ is any elementary substructure of $M$ containing $B$

Comment: Is this correct: first note that $T$ is tt (totally transcendental) implies that $\text{Th}_B(A)$ is tt. Then by (1) there is a model $M \models \text{Th}_B(A)$ such that $M$ is constructable over $B$; furthermore (2) gives that $M$ is atomic over $B$. Lastly, since $M \models \text{Th}_B(A)$ and $A$ is prime over $B$, we can $L_B$-elementary embed $A$ in $M$. So if there is some $a \in A$ such that $\text{tp}_A(a/B)$ is not isolated, also $\text{tp}_M(a/B)$ is not isolated, but it isn't. Therefore $A$ is atomic over $B$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.